# Export Google Analytics Embed API diagram to PNG & Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm need to export my Google Analytics Embed API chart To PNG (Or JPG) and Excel.

My diagram work correctly and there isn't any problem or error and I just want to export my data.

My current code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="auth-button"></section>
    <h2>Visits</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Usersers & Sessions over past week</legend>
        <section id="timelineWeek"></section>
    </fieldset>
  
  <script>
        (function (w, d, s, g, js, fjs) {
            g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {}); g.analytics = { q: [], ready: function (cb) { this.q.push(cb) } };
            js = d.createElement(s); fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); js.onload = function () { g.load('analytics') };
        }(window, document, 'script'));
    </script>

    <script>
        function BuildOptions(hAxis) {
            return {
                width: (window.innerWidth - 60), fontSize: 12,
                legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'center', textStyle: { fontSize: 16 } },
                series: { 0: { color: 'red' }, 1: { color: 'orange' } },
                hAxis: { title: hAxis }
            };
        }

        gapi.analytics.ready(function () {
            var GID = { query: { ids: 'ga:MYACCOUNTPROPERTY' } };
            var CLIENT_ID = 'MYSSECRETKEY';

            gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                container: 'auth-button',
                clientid: CLIENT_ID,
            });

            var timelineToday = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                reportType: 'ga',
                query: {
                    'dimensions': 'ga:hour',
                    'metrics': 'ga:users,ga:sessions',
                    'start-date': 'today',
                    'end-date': 'today',
                },,
                chart: {
                    type: 'LINE',
                    container: 'timelineWeek',
                    options: BuildOptions('Date')
                }
            });
            
          gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function (response) {
                timelineWeek.set(GID).execute();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also this is my chart snapshot:
[image]

Comment: You can use the [core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js) `gapi.analytics.data.ga.get(query)` to get the raw JSON response. With that you can use any technique known to you to convert that JSON response to charts or graphs or excel [spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). The embed API is good for making Auth easy in javascript as for general purpose image conversion or data conversion you seek tools that are specific for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a native way to export the chart from the [Google Analytics Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) like there is in the visualization API. You can either export the data from the [Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/), render it with another library (like the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)) and export it, or look into tools that help take screenshots like [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).